# Map projections

Tags: dictionary, projection

I am building a 'flat earth' 3D model of a small area of land for a simulation. Using google earth, I get the lat lon values for some grid lines near my chosen origin.

Then, using the [Vincenty distance algorithm](http://movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) I get xy distances from my origin to place the grid lines the right distance apart in my 'flat' 3D model.

In my simulation I use the [Vincenty 'Direct' algorithm](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty-direct.html) to display my players lat lon, all this works very well, and matches up well enough with google earth.

(There is a faster (less accurate) 'direct' algorithm [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (down page: 'Destination point given distance and bearing from start point
'))

If I measure a grid square where the degrees apart are 0.0036 in both lat and lon, the x value in meters is approx: 356.9 & the y value is approx: 400.9, This is pretty much the same as google earth, when I use it's measure tool. So basically a rectangle stretched a little in latitude. This suggests cylindrical projection? (Google use: wgs84/pseudo mercator (I think)) my model looks like a type of mercator.

So I have my homemade flat earth model that works fine, now for my question :-) (at last they say!)

What have I made? i.e. **what projection is it**?

(It would be nice if I could plug those values above into an app and out pops my projection!)

(The Vincenty algorthms use an Ellipsoid (WGS-84 in most cases) model.)

Anyway thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Are you basically assuming a region bounded by lat-long lines is a rectangle, with the lat-long lines being a linear mapping to a grid of metres? ie pretend its a flat region in lat-long? (so great near the equator, completely wrong at the poles)

Comment: hi spacedman, sounds about right, these rectangular boxes stretch as you go towards the poles (type of mercator?). I would just like a method to validate my model.

Comment: What do you even mean by 'validate'? Its a cylindrical projection of some flavour, yes, they just differ essentially by how they map latitude to y-coordinate. Mercator preserves shape, Peters preserves area, Plate Carree preserves, well, nothing much.

Comment: What I mean by 'validate': I can say to a client, this model's projection is 'mercator' or 'wgs84/pseudo mercator' etc

Comment: The more research I do, the more it looks like this method is producing a Mercator projection. I'll keep looking, but thanks for your help Spacedman.

Comment: Ok, using: http://www.apsalin.com/convert-geodetic-to-mercator.aspx my dimensions are very close, I will force my model to match these numbers & call my model 'Mercator'. I won't tag this as an answer, because I feel there is more to say on this huge subject...